# Swift: How do I change the position of my background every time the screen is touched?

Tags: ios, swift, background, sprite-kit

I want my background node to move down 50 pixels every time the screen is touched.

EDIT: Answer: I have two nodes of the same background so the background is wrapped, and every time the screen is touched, the background moves down 50 pixels.

```
   if bg.position.y + bg.size.height/2 < 50
    {
        let diff =  bg.position.y + bg.size.height/2 - 50
        bg.position.y = self.frame.height + bg.size.height/2 + diff
    }
    else
    {
        bg.position.y -= 50
    }
    if bg2.position.y + bg2.size.height/2 < 50
    {
        let diff =  bg2.position.y + bg2.size.height/2 - 50
        bg2.position.y = self.frame.height + bg2.size.height/2 + diff
    }
    else
    {
        bg2.position.y -= 50
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your backgrounds position?

```
background.position.y += 50.0
```

Comment: did not work.  the simulator crashes once I test it.  I want it to change position in the y direction every time the screen is touched.